# Best way to avoid duplication of related objects in the actions new and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To create an user in the example bellow I have to load  `@projects` and `@companies` as they are mandatory for creating user.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    # duplication here
    @projects = Project.all
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      # and here
      @projects = Project.all
      @companies = Company.all
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

I have to load these dependencies in both (duplication) cases, for the new and create action when the user is invalid.

I can refactor by encapsulating these dependencies in a method `load_user_dependencies`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    load_user_dependencies
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      load_user_dependencies
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def load_user_dependencies
      @projects = Project.all
      @companies = Company.all
  end
end
```

Or by adding them as a helper_methods.

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :projects, :companies

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def projects
    @projects ||= Project.all
  end

  def companies
    @companies ||= Company.all
  end
end
```

I can also create a [View Object](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

```
class UserView
  def products
    @products ||= Product.all
  end

  def companies
    @companies ||= Company.all
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @user = User.new
     @user_view = UserView.new
   end

   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
       redirect_to @user
     else
       @user_view = UserView.new
       render :action => "new"
     end
   end
 end
```

Other option is to use a [Presenter](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html)

```
class UserPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  def products
     @products ||= Product.all
  end

  def companies
    @companies ||= Company.all
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @user = UserPresenter.new User.new
   end

   def create
    @user = UserPresenter.new User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
       redirect_to @user
     else
       render :action => "new"
     end
   end
 end
```

How do you guys usually deal with scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a personal taste issue, but in our projects if it's suitable we do it in the view, and if it's complex we do it in a before_filter.

View - suitable if it's something that doesn't have any logic, no need to create a variable for this. Super useful if your form is contained in a partial as it's only done once so easily maintained.

```
<%= form.select :project_id, Project.all, :id, :name %>
```

If it's something that can change depending on any factors then a before_filter in controller:

```
MyController
  before_filter :find_projects, :except => [:destroy, :some_method] # Will load the values but not for the destroy or some_method actions

  def find_projects
    @projects = Project.where(:some conditions => true)
  end
```

Comment: +1 for before filter usage. Also too, if there is no need to execute the query for every controller action, the `:only` or `except` keys can be used. Example: `before_filter :find_projects, :only => [:new, :create]`

Comment: Thanks @Teeg, have added an except example.

Comment: I will update my examples. Sometimes isn't only Resource.all there are cases that I need to parse/format data that belongs to the view, not specific to the model. The problem with before_filter is that it will be loaded always for the creation action, not only in case of user is invalid. before_filter is for actions not for views

Comment: The way you describe it, your second example is how I would do it, allowing for the before_filter to call the load method for actions that don't have any options, and then manually call it where appropriate. I think you're probably overthinking this!

Comment: I usually extract into a presenter because it is easier to test.